# Do irrotational vector fields have zero curl in all coordinate systems (including coordinate systems with a different origin)?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

For example, I have two points A and B, and I can prove that the electric field produced by a point charge sitting at A is irrotational with respect to the spherical polar coordinate system that has its origin at A. If I express the electric field of said charge, which sits at point A, with respect to the spherical polar coordinate system that has its origin at B and calculate the field's curl, will I find that the curl in this system is also zero?

(I know physics says "any electrostatic field is irrotational", I'm just trying to figure out whether or not that can be proved mathematically using the above argument)

Comment: The formula for the curl in spherical coordinates is *by design* supposed to match the curl (at a given point) in rectangular coordinates. Or else it wouldn't be a formula for the curl, would it?

Comment: @runway44 I understand that the curl formula in spherical coordinates is designed to give the same result (at a given point) with the curl formula in cartesian coordinates, if these two coordinate systems have the same origin. What I'm wondering is whether the curl formula for spherical coordinates, which gives "0" when applied to a certain vector field that's described in terms of spherical coordinate system A, will give me a nonzero result if I apply it to the same vector field described in terms of spherical coordinate system B which has a different origin than system A.

Comment: The curl in rectangular coordinates is translation-invariant (in the sense that if you translate, take the curl, then translate back, you get what you would have gotten if you just took the curl to begin with); it's agnostic about what the origin even is. If both spherical coordinates' curls match the rectangular coordinates' curl, then the two spherical coordinates curls match each other.

Comment: @runway44 Oh right this makes perfect sense! Thank you very much for your responses!